# Replace unwanted characters for filename in Visual Basic

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have a VB script for a Word 2013 template, which select fields to put the filename together.

How can I replace all unwanted letters, signs and special characters for a filename as string?

Here's the script:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions ' wrong?

Sub FileSave()

If ActiveDocument.Path = "" Then
    FileSaveAs
    Exit Sub
End If
ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
Sub FileSaveAs()

Dim DocName As String

If (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Datum") = True) And (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Betreff") = True) And (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Bezug") = True) Then
    a = Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Datum").Range.Text)
    b = Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Betreff").Range.Text)
    c = Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bezug").Range.Text)
    DocName = a & " - " & b & " - " & c
    DocName = Replace(DocName, "/^*\s*/$", "") ' wrong

Else
    DocName = ActiveDocument.Name
End If

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = DocName
    .Show
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something similar to this for these situations. You can change it as you see fit but it replaces all characters that are special in Windows files paths with underscores.

```
Function CreateFriendlyName(pText as string) as String

    Dim objRegex As Object

    ' Initiate regex search
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "(\s|\\|/|<|>|\|\|\?|:)"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With

    CreateFriendlyName = objRegex.Replace(pText , "_")

    Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What does this function return?

Comment: Yeah... obviously missed some parts. Thanks for edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function CreateFriendlyName(pText As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object

' Initiate regex search
Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "(\s|\\|/|<|>|\|\|\?|:)"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With

CreateFriendlyName = objRegex.Replace(pText, "_")
Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function


Sub FileSave()

If ActiveDocument.Path = "" Then
    FileSaveAs
    Exit Sub
End If
ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
Sub FileSaveAs()

Dim DocName As String

If (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Datum") = True) And (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Betreff") = True) And (ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Bezug") = True) Then
    a = Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Datum").Range.Text)
    b = Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Betreff").Range.Text)
    c = Trim(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bezug").Range.Text)
    DocName = a & " - " & b & " - " & c
    DocName = CreateFriendlyName(DocName)

Else
    DocName = ActiveDocument.Name
End If

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = DocName
    .Show
End With

End Sub
```